# How to reduce size of data coming in Web API Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi

I have a table in the SQL Server database and this table containing records 4,64,872 having 76 columns fields. When I hit API for listing this data, it shows up to 85MB data and taking more time to display.

Please help!!!

Comment: Are you returning only what your client needs?

Comment: Does you client (web client, or mobile client) actually need all of this data at once? I doubt it.
Maybe you could paginate your requests?

Comment: @Florin-ConstantinCiubotariu Yes Sir

Comment: @QwertyQwerty web client - yes sir. A client wants data at once time. But Right now, I'm using pagination for showing some data. But need to show all data.

Comment: @NitikaChopra can you show us how is the response structured? Maybe you can change the response format and make it smaller.

Comment: @NitikaChopra if you cant use pagination maybe you should try lazy loading?